# Teamcity issue with release mode

Tags: .net, build, configuration, teamcity

We have a TeamCity project for building our .NET applications, using .NET as the build runner.
Even after setting the configuration and command line to release mode, but still output was pointing to debug mode.

Build log output:

```
Step 3/5: MS Build For SQL (.NET)
16:12:48
  dotnet msbuild
16:12:48
    Starting: .NET SDK 7.0.100 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" msbuild D:\_tcba\ba3\work\e1f7304223bb8d02\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.SQLDataSource\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.SQLDataSource.csproj /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release @D:\_tcba\ba3\temp\agentTmp\2.rsp /p:configuration=release /p:DebugSymbols=false;DebugType=None
16:12:48
    in directory: D:\_tcba\ba3\work\e1f7304223bb8d02
16:12:48
    MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
16:12:51
      Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.Contracts -> D:\_tcba\ba3\work\e1f7304223bb8d02\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.Contracts\bin\Debug\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.Contracts.dll
16:12:52
    D:\_tcba\ba3\work\e1f7304223bb8d02\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.SQLDataSource\Repositories\SiteStatusRepository.cs(30,28): warning CS0618: 'TimeZone' is obsolete: 'System.TimeZone has been deprecated.  Please investigate the use of System.TimeZoneInfo instead.'
16:12:52
      Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.SQLDataSource -> D:\_tcba\ba3\work\e1f7304223bb8d02\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.SQLDataSource\bin\Debug\Gabriels.CMS.AdminTool.SQLDataSource.dll
16:12:52
     [32;1m
16:12:52
    Build succeeded.
```

Is there anything need to change on TC Administration part or other?

I have tried by changing the configuration and command line to release mode like below.

```
Configuration: Release; 
Command line parameters: /p:configuration=release
```

But no luck on my end